# My Android app network detect method has semantic error and back pressed method showing syntax while it was fine before?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have built a simple app with webview and trying to implement network detect method. Already edited manifest.xml by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The problem is in two parts; one my app has a backpress method which was working fine at the place it is right now but after adding functionality for network detect it has started to show syntax error.

The complete code of my MainActivity.Java:

```
package pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog prDialog;
    public WebView view;
    NetworkDetect myNetworkstate;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myNetworkstate = new NetworkDetect(this);

            if (myNetworkstate.isConnected()) {

            String url = "http://shippingexpress.pk";
            view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.express);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            view.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
            view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            view.clearHistory();
            view.clearCache(true);
            view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
            view.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

            ActionBar myicon = getSupportActionBar();
            myicon.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            myicon.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                public void onBackPressed(){
                    if (view.canGoBack()) {
                        view.goBack();
                    } else

                    {
                        //otherwise exit my app
                        super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "INTERNET NOT AVAILABLE !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }




    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Second part; I made a class NetworkDetect.java to detect network state and used in my application with if statement as you can see in MainActivity.java. Unfortunately my program runs fine in two conditions one internet is available ,secondly backpress method commented as it has a syntax error.

But when internet connectivity is not available I expect my app to show an error when opened as you can see in else part, rather it shows "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped working" and exit

The complete code for NetworkDetect.java:

```
package pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkDetect{

    Context context;

    public NetworkDetect(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

        public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info != null) {
                if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }

            return false;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have tried the solution proposed in comments. First part has resolved but second part still needs elaboration. If there is no internet available app crashes rather showing error as you may see in else part of the MainActivity.java.

The error I am receiving in Android Studio at crash is as following:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress, PID: 1660
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress/pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:111)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your brackets. You now have `onBackPressed()` inside `onCreate()`. Move it out of that method

Comment: Your code's braces are miss placed.

Comment: Thank you codeMagic & Muhammad Faisal Hyder syntax error gone what about second part please figure out.... thanks again

Comment: Return false inside else from 2nd class

Comment: Muahammad Faisal Hyder please give hint at which place on 2 class should I place  return false with else statement...... when i put else at the same place where false returned it starts show error at second last brace of the class NetworkDetect.java please where to put it.

Comment: putting return false in else starts to show up compile time errors

pk.shippingexpress.shippingexpress.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:108)

Comment: What is your stack trace of a crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to my question myself, posting here for the guidance of others if anyone is in the same situation.

you may read my MainActivity.java there were some extra lines of code which was auto generated by android studio and that was causing problem (you may read the whole question) there was no braces issue and nothings wrong with my code i simply removed following auto-generated lines and now my app is working absolutely in desired way.

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Thank you.